# Node state=down with TORQUE v6.1.0 on a Workstation

Tags: linux, torque, cgroups

I was installing Torque 6.1.0 on a Ubuntu 16.04 Workstation, but the
installation doesn't seem to recognize how many cores and threads the
machine has. The only node I set up showed a status of "state=down" and
any job would trigger an error saying "not enough of the right type
of nodes". In fact, the workstation has 56 threads or 28 physical cores
on 2 processors, and I only want to use 54 threads or 27 physical cores
for the shared computing jobs. I realized that this might be related to the configuration of cgroup or NUMA starting from Torque V6.0 which I am not if I was doing the right thing while installing. I indeed had the `cgroup` enabled, but not sure if I also need to configure NUMA-aware function to be enabled as well. Below are some outputs of current configs. What should I do? Thanks.

```
$ pbsnodes
node1
 state = down
 power_state = Running
 np = 54
 ntype = cluster
 mom_service_port = 15002
 mom_manager_port = 15003
 total_sockets = 0
 total_numa_nodes = 0
 total_cores = 0
 total_threads = 0
 dedicated_sockets = 0
 dedicated_numa_nodes = 0
 dedicated_cores = 0
 dedicated_threads = 0


$ lssubsys -am
cpuset /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cpu,cpuacct /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
blkio /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
memory /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
devices /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
freezer /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
net_cls,net_prio /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
perf_event /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
hugetlb /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
pids /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
```

There is also a fishy part that it seems the server cannot see the node I defined already on the server's configure file. This can be seen on the `/var/spool/torque/server_logs` log file:

```
12/27/2016 15:48:33.147;01;PBS_Server.2692;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::get_node_from_str, Node node1 is reporting on node NapaValley, which pbs_server doesn't know about
12/27/2016 15:49:18.232;01;PBS_Server.2692;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::get_node_from_str, Node node1 is reporting on node NapaValley, which pbs_server doesn't know about
12/27/2016 15:49:25.491;08;PBS_Server.2696;Job;0.NapaValley;Job deleted at request of cquic@localhost
12/27/2016 15:49:27.023;08;PBS_Server.2657;Job;0.NapaValley;on_job_exit valid pjob: 0.NapaValley (substate=59)
12/27/2016 15:49:32.996;256;PBS_Server.2657;Job;0.NapaValley;dequeuing from batch, state COMPLETE
12/27/2016 15:49:59.722;256;PBS_Server.2696;Job;1.NapaValley;enqueuing into batch, state 1 hop 1
12/27/2016 15:49:59.722;08;PBS_Server.2696;Job;perform_commit_work;job_id: 1.NapaValley
12/27/2016 15:49:59.722;02;PBS_Server.2696;node;close_conn;Closing connection 9 and calling its accompanying function on close
12/27/2016 15:49:59.795;64;PBS_Server.2692;Req;node_spec;job allocation request exceeds currently available cluster nodes, 1 requested, 0 available
12/27/2016 15:49:59.796;08;PBS_Server.2692;Job;1.NapaValley;Job Modified at request of root@localhost
12/27/2016 15:50:03.312;01;PBS_Server.2696;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::get_node_from_str, Node node1 is reporting on node NapaValley, which pbs_server doesn't know about
```

On my `/etc/hosts`, I have

```
127.0.0.1 localhost node1
127.0.0.1 NapaValley
```

PS: I have tried to mount cpu and other modules to `/var/spool/torque/cgroup` directories, but `lssubsys -am` still showed the same information as above. I assume they should have been mounted?

Comment: Did you configure with hwloc?

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/9-1-0/installGuide/RH6/help.htm#topics/hpcSuiteInstall/manual/installing/installingTorque.htm#hwloc

It requires version 1.9.1+

And under 2.2.3 ("Install Torque Server)":
2. Depending on your system configuration, you will need to add ./configure command options.
At a minimum, you add:
‑‑enable‑cgroups
‑‑with‑hwloc‑path=/usr/local See 1.2.1 Torque for more information.

You also need to install cgroup-tools ***AND hwloc*** *on the compute nodes*.

Comment: I had hwloc 1.11.5 installed from source. cgroup-tools were installed from the Ubuntu package repo. When I run configure, I used `./configure --enable-cgroups --with-hwloc-path=/usr/local` as you pointed out based on the manual. Since the node is exactly on the server for my workstation, I think I don't need to reinstall the hwloc, right?

Comment: Oh, sorry...I missed your server log lines about the node. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A node will report to the server with a name returned by the gethostbyname call. Based on the log lines you posted, the server and the node don't agree on that name. You can have pbs_mom return a different name by starting it with the -H option:

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-0-2/adminGuide/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/pbs_mom.htm#-h

"`-H`   hostname    Sets the MOM's hostname. This can be useful on multi-homed networks."

This is equivalent to setting `$mom_host node1` in `/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config`.

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution. I had solved this problem by using the server's name as the node's name and setting `log_level=7`. I think maybe your solution will also work, but I am tired of trying now as this problem has taken me a week to figure out a working solution. Anyway, this might be helpful for others and should be rewarded for your efforts!